# Setting up JDesktopPane as Accessible Parent to JInternal Frame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I want to set JDesktopPane as Accessible Parent to JInternal Frame. But JInternalFrame properties does not show JdesktopPane on accessible parent's list. My MDI application has JdesktopPane and Internal Frames load on top of JdesktopPane. I have problem with setting up Requestfocus to textfiled on InternalFrame at the form load, may be due to this parent issue. Can someone assist me Please. P.S : This is Java Swing Application. IDE- Netbeans

Comment: Pass the instance of the JDesktopPane to the JInternalFrames.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Thanx for your reply. But could you give me little more explanation how to do that. Please

Comment: In the constructors of the classes you set the JInternalFrame as a variable (remember, composition over inheritance), you pass an instance of the JDesktopPane as a variable.